# How can I make a function pointer parameter no-op by default?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, function-pointers

Given my function that takes a function pointer as parameter

```
void call_func(std::function<void()>func) {
    func();
}
```

The most straight forward way is something like

```
void no_op() {
    ;
}

void call_func(std::function<void()>func = no_op) {
    func();
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this so that I can avoid creating the literally useless `no_op` function?

Comment: use a `lambda`?

Comment: Or use `nullptr` and change the body to `if (func) func();`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a no-op "do nothing" function object exist in C++(0x)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982592/does-a-no-op-do-nothing-function-object-exist-in-c0x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an empty [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), which could be also wrapped by [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). e.g.

```
void call_func(std::function<void()>func = []{}) {
    func();
}
```

Comment: Maybe force a decay first `+[]{}` - The way in the default  case the `std::function` won't need to allocate any storage.